# Clang error while compiling Rcpp package in Big Sur

Tags: gcc, clang, rcpp, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to compile an Rcpp package and am currently running Big Sur (mistake, apparently). I've installed and updated Xcode, as well as CLANG as instructed [here](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#after-3-4-0). However, I get the following error when attempting to build:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is strange for many reasons; first of all, my gfortran directory is `L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0`.

My ~/.R/Makevars file is setup as such:

```
CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX1X=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX17=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

Comment: Not a macOS user myself -- but I recall there being issues with an extra download needed for fortran and quadmath.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I downloaded the ARM version of Gfortran on Github; do you know what the additional required downloads might be?

Comment: I do not know, not a macOS user myself.  I suggest you inquire with the r-sig-macos list, or maybe the rcpp-devel list.  Why Arm?  Are you on an M1?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am, and that's the recommended version on the R website. To be honest, I'm very new to all of this, so apologies to bother!

Comment: It is absolutely no bother at all, but I just don't have the detailed macOS knowledge to help you, esp on the still rather new (and not yet formally supported by R -- only R 4.1.0 in April) platform.  Maybe try the lists.

Answer (score 2):

Few quick notes I'm leaving as an answer (sorta) to the compilation issue with ARM.

1. the post linked to is a bit old (latest update 2017 / R 3.4.0) and was geared toward incorporating OpenMP into old versions of R. I'll make sure to update it later today to emphasize this.
2. the focus was on using Intel-based macs since the ARM architecture (e.g. M1 chip) wasn't announced.

With that being said, our attention now turns to the elephant in the room: ARM and Big Sur. Presently, there is no native/ARM-compiled versions of R and gfortran available outside of [developer nightlies on the macOS R developer portal](https://mac.r-project.org/#nightly).

The best approach here is to run R and gfortran through [Rosetta 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/about_the_rosetta_translation_environment) (e.g. use a non-native version) until R 4.1.0 is released this upcoming April.

For more in-depth analysis, see: [Will R Work on Apple Silicon?](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/11/02/will-r-work-on-apple-silicon/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer version of recommendations regarding gfortran and clang from The Coatless Professor here:
[R COMPILER TOOLS FOR RCPP ON MACOS](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/)

One of the updates is that they no longer recommend using `~/.R/Makevars`.

Note that this only addresses through Catalina (10.15), though it is for R version 4.y.z (the one linked was for R 3). Theoretically, it may also work for Big Sur. I haven't found a solution yet, but I'm running Big Sur on an Intel Mac (not M1/ARM).

Apologies for answering rather than commenting, but I can't comment yet (too new).